# Issues with background downloader Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am having issues downloading multiple files with the Background Downloader. I'm getting an "Object not set to an instance of an Object" error in my `HandleDownloadAsync` method. Here is my code.

```
    private async Task StartDownload(List<DownloadData> data)
    {
        foreach (DownloadData song in data)
        {
            Uri source = new Uri(song.downloadUrl);

            // Create folder stucture
            StorageFolder artistFolder = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFolderAsync(song.artistName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            StorageFolder releaseFolder = await artistFolder.CreateFolderAsync(song.releaseName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            // Create file
            StorageFile destinationFile;
            try
            {
                destinationFile = await releaseFolder.CreateFileAsync(song.fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);

            List<DownloadOperation> requestOperations = new List<DownloadOperation>();
            requestOperations.Add(download);

            await HandleDownloadAsync(download, true);
        }
    }
```

and the method

```
    private async Task HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation download, bool start)
    {
        try
        {
            // Store the download for pause/resume
            activeDownloads.Add(download); // Error occurs here

            Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
            if (start)
            {
                await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
            }
            else
            {
                await download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            activeDownloads.Remove(download);
        }
    }
```

The error get thrown when trying to add the download to `activeDownloads`. Most of the code is from [This](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61/sourcecode?fileId=52027&pathId=738703904) MSDN sample, but I added the foreach loop to download multiple items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you may have forgotten to initalize the activeDownloads list in your StartDownload method, for example like so:

```
activeDownloads = new List<DownloadOperation>();
```